# $y=x/(1+a(x))$, $\quad$ $x=y/(1+b(y))$. What is known about $a\mapsto b$?

Tags: inverse, integer-partitions, inverse-function, involutions

\begin{align}
y & = f(x) = \frac x {\displaystyle 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}} \\[15pt]
x & = f^{-1}(y) = \frac y {\displaystyle 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \frac{y^n}{n!}}
\end{align}
One obvious case of the identities above is this:
$$
y = \frac x {1- x}, \qquad x = \frac y {1+y}.
$$
What is known about the nature of the mapping $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) \mapsto b = (b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots) \text{?}$

Clearly $a\mapsto b$ is an involution.

Each $b_n$ is a polynomial in $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. The coefficients are integers.  In the $n$th term of the polynomial, the sum of the indices (i.e. the subscripts) is $n$. Thus each term corresponds to a partition of $n$. One must wonder what the combinatorial interpretation of the coefficients is.

Comment: Isn't this at a high enough level for math overflow?

Comment: @Ovi : Could be. I thought there might be some standard answer found in books, but maybe not. $\qquad$